# specific day of next month on a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, where-clause

I have a complex (complex because it gave me lots of work to complete!) and it returns results that fulfill the query till the day 30 of the current month.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(' ', CONVERT(date, fc.dataven), ' '), 
    fc.adoc, fc.nome, 
    CONCAT(CONVERT(money, fc.ecred), '  €')  
FROM
    fc, fl
WHERE
    dataven BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, YEAR(GETDATE())-1, YEAR(GETDATE())),
                                  IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, 12, MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1), 30) 
                AND CAST(DATEADD(day,-day(GETDATE()),DATEADD(month, 1,GETDATE())) as DATE)

    AND fc.adoc NOT LIKE '' 
    AND fc.cmdesc LIKE 'v%'  
    AND fc.evalpo = '0' 
    AND (fc.cmdesc LIKE '%factura%' OR fc.cmdesc LIKE '%cred%')
    AND fc.nome = fl.nome 
    AND fl.pais LIKE 1
GROUP BY
    fc.adoc, fc.dataven, fc.nome, fc.ecred
ORDER BY 
    fc.nome
```

I have a job that runs this query on the third monday of every month.

What i need is that the query returns values not only till the 30th day of the current month but till the 10th day of the next month.

I'm a bit lost, can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Not all months have 30 days. Which boundaries you want for the month of February?

Comment: `FROM fc, fl` -> please stop doing this. Use a proper `INNER JOIN` to separate join criteria from filter criteria. Also, please show some sample data and desired results, so we don't have to reverse engineer your massive `BETWEEN` expression to understand your word problem. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the shortest way would be to use `EOMONTH` function

```
    dataven between dateadd(day, -5, eomonth(getdate(), -1))
                and dateadd(day, 10, eomonth(getdate(), 0))
```

Comment: The problem is `dataven` doesn't look like it's a `date` type (otherwise there wouldn't be an explicit `CONVERT`). `BETWEEN` is a bad choice here because it will leave out any data on the end day _after_ midnight. You could convert `dataven` in the where clause, and still get a seek, but [there are problems with that](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). I would rather use >= the start date and < the day _after_ the end date. Also note this will only yield the 25th of the previous month when that month has 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase the `where` predicate as:

```
dataven between eomonth(getdate()) and dateadd(day, 11, eomonth(getdate()))
```

This filters on dates between the last day of the current month and the 10th day of next month. This is not exactly what you ask for, but it seems like a reasonable way to address the question - not all months have exactly 30 days (actually, there are just 4 months in the year that have 30 days).

---

**Edit**

From the comments:

> I need the query to work between the day 25 of the prior month till the day 10 of the next month

That's not the same thing. You can phrase this as:

```
where dataven 
    between dateadd(day, 24, dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)))
        and dateadd(day,  9, dateadd(month,  1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)))
```

This assumes that `dataven` has no time component. Otherwise, you probably would prefer:

```
where dataven >= dateadd(day, 24, dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)))
  and dataven <  dateadd(day, 10, dateadd(month,  1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB 
Getting the following problem, in a perfect world i need the query to work between the day 25 of the prior month till the day 10 of the next month. Furthermor, getting this message:
'eof' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @questionador: *i need the query to work between the day 25 of the prior month till the day 10 of the next month*: day 25 of the prior month is reallty not the same thing as day 30 of the current month, so your comment is unclear to me.

Comment: So, I will try to explain, sorry. The query, like i have it, returns results from the day 30 of last month and the last day of the current month, right? I need it to work from the day 25 of last month (this part i can work it out) and the day 10 of next month, and this part i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would perform the expressions outside of the query because they are much easier to test and debug that way, and they keep your query cleaner and easier to maintain as well.

```
DECLARE @lastmonth date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, sysdatetime());
DECLARE @nextmonth date = DATEADD(MONTH,  2, @lastmonth);

DECLARE @start date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@lastmonth), MONTH(@lastmonth), 25),    
        @end   date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@nextmonth), MONTH(@nextmonth), 11);

SELECT 
  ...
  FROM dbo.fc INNER JOIN dbo.fl
    ON fc.nome = fl.nome 
  WHERE dataven >= @start AND dataven < @end
  ...
```

Some further reading:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Simplify date period calculations](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)